# Unfortunately, "application" has stopped

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, navigationbar

I'm using Navigation Bar which contains menu Home, Hospital, Doctors and Restaurant and use Fragment to move one to other fragment but when click on Doctor menu application has stopped.

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);
        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new BlankFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("GApp");

        navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.home:
                         fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new BlankFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.hospital:
                        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new HospitalFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hospitals");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.doctor:
                        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new DoctorFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Doctors");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                    case R.id.restaurent:
                        fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,new restaurent());
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Restaurents");
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
}
```

***DoctorFragment.java***

```
public class DoctorFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    String[] doctors={"Physician","Child Specialist","Dentist","Neurologist"};

    public DoctorFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       listView=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
       ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_view_custom_layout,doctors);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doctor, container, false);
    }

}
```

So, is this your layout?

```
<FrameLayout 
  xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   tools:context="com.example.nk.gapp.DoctorFragment">
  <ListView 
     android:id="@+id/listview" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ListView> 
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: what does the logcat say?

Comment: listView.setAdapter(adapter);   //listview=null  when debug app

Comment: Try my answer below

Comment: it seems you haven't inflated any content in onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this change to your fragment: since you have not shared the logcat, it is hard to point to the real cause: Inflate your view first, then find the listview by id, set adapter as usual and then finally return the view.

```
public class DoctorFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    String[] doctors={"Physician","Child Specialist","Dentist","Neurologist"};

    public DoctorFragment() {

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_doctor, container, false);

       listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

       ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_view_custom_layout,doctors);
       listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
     }

}
```

Comment: Frame? This is strange; can you show the layout for this fragment?

Comment: <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nk.gapp.DoctorFragment">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</FrameLayout>